# Select Data from multiple rows to one row

Tags: pyspark

I'm pretty new to functional programming and pyspark and I currently struggle to condense the data I want from my source data

Let's say I have two tables as DataFrames:

```
# if not already created automatically, instantiate Sparkcontext
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

columns = ['Id', 'JoinId', 'Name']
vals = [(1, 11, 'FirstName'), (2, 12, 'SecondName'), (3, 13, 'ThirdName')]
persons = spark.createDataFrame(vals,columns)
columns = ['Id', 'JoinId', 'Specification', 'Date', 'Destination']
vals = [(1, 10, 'I', '20051205', 'New York City'), (2, 11, 'I', '19991112', 'Berlin'), (3, 11, 'O', '20030101', 'Madrid'), (4, 13, 'I', '20200113', 'Paris'), (5, 11, 'U', '20070806', 'Lissabon')]
movements = spark.createDataFrame(vals,columns)

persons.show()
+---+------+----------+
| Id|JoinId|      Name|
+---+------+----------+
|  1|    11| FirstName|
|  2|    12|SecondName|
|  3|    13| ThirdName|
+---+------+----------+

movements.show()
+---+------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| Id|JoinId|Specification|    Date|  Destination|
+---+------+-------------+--------+-------------+
|  1|    10|            I|20051205|New York City|
|  2|    11|            I|19991112|       Berlin|
|  3|    11|            O|20030101|       Madrid|
|  4|    13|            I|20200113|        Paris|
|  5|    11|            U|20070806|     Lissabon|
+---+------+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

What I want to create is

```
+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+
|PersonId|PersonName|    IDate|    ODate|Destination|
|       1| FirstName| 19991112| 20030101|     Berlin|
|       3| ThirdName| 20200113|         |      Paris|
+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

The rules would be:

1. PersonId is the Id of the Person
2. IDate is the Date saved in the Movements DataFrame where Specification is I
3. ODate the Date saved in the Movements DataFrame where Specification is O
4. The Destination is the Destination of the joined entry where the Specification was I

I already joined the dataframes on JoinId

```
joined = persons.withColumnRenamed('JoinId', 'P_JoinId').join(movements, col('P_JoinId') == movements.JoinId, how='inner')

joined.show()
+---+--------+---------+---+------+-------------+--------+-----------+
| Id|P_JoinId|     Name| Id|JoinId|Specification|    Date|Destination|
+---+--------+---------+---+------+-------------+--------+-----------+
|  1|      11|FirstName|  2|    11|            I|19991112|     Berlin|
|  1|      11|FirstName|  3|    11|            O|20030101|     Madrid|
|  1|      11|FirstName|  5|    11|            U|20070806|   Lissabon|
|  3|      13|ThirdName|  4|    13|            I|20200113|      Paris|
+---+--------+---------+---+------+-------------+--------+-----------+
```

But I'm struggling to select data from multiple rows and put them with the given rules into a single row...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you please add the desired output?

Comment: It is mentioned after "What I want to create is..." :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : I have renamed the id in movements to Id_Movements,to avoid confusion in grouping later.

You can pivot your joined data based on the specification and do some aggregation on date and destination. Then you will get the date and destination specification wise.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
persons =sqlContext.createDataFrame( [(1, 11, 'FirstName'), (2, 12, 'SecondName'), (3, 13, 'ThirdName')],schema=['Id', 'JoinId', 'Name'])
movements=sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, 10, 'I', '20051205', 'New York City'), (2, 11, 'I', '19991112', 'Berlin'), (3, 11, 'O', '20030101', 'Madrid'), (4, 13, 'I', '20200113', 'Paris'), (5, 11, 'U', '20070806', 'Lissabon')],schema=['Id_movements', 'JoinId', 'Specification', 'Date', 'Destination'])
df_joined = persons.withColumnRenamed('JoinId', 'P_JoinId').join(movements, F.col('P_JoinId') == movements.JoinId, how='inner')
#%%
df_pivot = df_joined.groupby(['Id','Name']).pivot('Specification').agg(F.min('Date').alias("date"),F.min('Destination').alias('destination'))
```

Here I have chosen the min aggregation, but you can choose the one as per your need and drop the irrelevant columns

results :

```
+---+---------+--------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| Id|     Name|  I_date|I_destination|  O_date|O_destination|  U_date|U_destination|
+---+---------+--------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+-------------+
|  1|FirstName|19991112|       Berlin|20030101|       Madrid|20070806|     Lissabon|
|  3|ThirdName|20200113|        Paris|    null|         null|    null|         null|
+---+---------+--------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I will check that out!

Comment: That's quite interesting. I've never worked with pivot before. How would the next step look like to condense the resulting three rows (person 1) into one row?

Comment: just added the results  in the answer. you need not condense again. Based on the grouping , it already does the condensing based on the aggregation you choose. May be you may have to do some column dropping and renamin

Comment: you're welcome. Thank you too for framing the question perfectly, with all the needed code to generate the sample.